# Kernel 3.13 on Ubuntu ARM + Android kernel options compatibility

Tags: 12.04, android, arm, chromebook

I've installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS with the kernel 3.13 on my ARM Samsung / Google Chromebook,using this tutorial :

http://www.virtualopensystems.com/en/solutions/guides/kvm-on-chromebook/

I have to say that ubuntu works really good. Now I would like to add the Android kernel options inside the .config file of the kernel.

Can you explain to me,please,why when I add the options listed below to the kernel they disappear after the recompilation ? If I look inside the .config file after the kernel is re-compiled,I don't see them anymore !! These are the options that I need to enable :

```
CONFIG_ANDROID=y
CONFIG_ANDROID_BINDER_IPC=y
CONFIG_ASHMEM=y
CONFIG_ANDROID_LOGGER=y
CONFIG_ANDROID_PERSISTENT_RAM=y
CONFIG_ANDROID_RAM_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_ANDROID_TIMED_OUTPUT=y
CONFIG_ANDROID_LOW_MEMORY_KILLER=y
```

maybe because this kernel is not compatible with Android ? What should I do to make it what I want ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will happens,
Kindly keep android source and navigate to the directory

`/android-kernel/arch/arm/config/` copy the android configuration your are required to use.

if your using x86 architecture as host machine then,

copy and paste say `msm_defconfig` to `/andorid-kernel/arch/arm/x86/`

now compile your android kernel you will get all your settings.

```
CONFIG_ANDROID=y
CONFIG_ANDROID_BINDER_IPC=y
CONFIG_ASHMEM=y
CONFIG_ANDROID_LOGGER=y
CONFIG_ANDROID_PERSISTENT_RAM=y
CONFIG_ANDROID_RAM_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_ANDROID_TIMED_OUTPUT=y
CONFIG_ANDROID_LOW_MEMORY_KILLER=y
```